# Unfortunately, PushWoosh Cordova has stopped / Any Ideas?

Tags: android, pushwoosh

I've spent the better part of the past 3 weeks working with Sencha Touch and more recently with Eclipse trying to achieve Push Notification functionality. Using the Android/PhoneGap SDK at Pushwoosh I've built a demo app with Eclipse. When I run the app in Debug mode there are no errors, the Emulator starts and the .apk loads. When I click the PushWoosh Cordova app it errors with the message: 'unfortunately, PushWoosh Cordova has stopped'. When I put the app on my Galaxy S3 it gives the same message. The manifest.xml has all the permissions including: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET", uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE", uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE", uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".

Any thoughts as to why this might be happening and how to proceed? Thanks in advance.

Rob

Might this be because there is no generated Javadoc?  Here are the logcat logs:

```
Pushwoosh Sample Phonegap [Android Application] 
    DalvikVM[localhost:12215]   
        Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
            <VM does not provide monitor information>   
            ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2106    
            ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2230 
            ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 141    
            ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1234  
            ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
            Lo`enter code here`oper.loop() line: 137    
            ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5041    
            Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
            Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
            ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 793  
            ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 560 
            NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
        Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
        Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running)
```

Comment: You need to look at the log output from the device to see what went wrong: you should see a stack trace there. If you can't interpret it for yourself, add it to your question.

Comment: Open logcat and watch detailed logs. And use IntelliJ Idea Community insteard of eclipse